# Flask WTForms POST form error - validation error

Tags: python, flask, webforms, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I've been working on a project recently with Flask and have been stuck on one very annoying problem. I ended up making a simpler version to try make me understand the problem. It seems like all the inputs I am typing in the input boxes seem to be ignored and therefore the form is not validating.

**Python Code - main.py**

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "*****"

class UserForm(Form):
    username = StringField("Please enter a username", validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField("Please enter a email", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Sign Up")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    username = None
    form = UserForm()
    print("######### ABOUT TO CHECK ###########")
    #if form.validate_on_submit():
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        return 'Form Successfully Submitted!'
        username = form.username.data
        form.username.data = ''
        email = form.email.data
        form.password.data = ''
    else:
        print('Needs more work....')
    return render_template("page.html",
                          form=form,
                          username=username)
```

**HTML Code - page.html**

```
{% block content %}
{% if username %}
    <h1>Hello {{ username }}!!</h1>
{% else %}
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.username.label }}
        {{ form.username() }}
        </br>
        {{ form.email.label }}
        {{ form.email() }}
        </br>
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have attempted using FlaskForm with 'for.hidden_tag()' however there was a problem with the CSRF token being missing (that may of occurred due to this problem).

When I run the code, before and after entering the inputs this appears on the console...

```
######### ABOUT TO CHECK ###########
Needs more work....
172.31.128.1 - - [08/Dec/2022 12:54:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The 'ABOUT TO CHECK' and 'Needs more work...' are comments from me to check for the error.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: pls add the imports you have, it will ease the debugging.

Comment: Try adding `{{ form.csrf_token }}` in your form.

Comment: Please add error message(s) as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, this looks like you are missing [`{{ form.csrf_token }}` from your form](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/csrf/).

Try this:

```html
{% block content %}
{% if username %}
    <h1>Hello {{ username }}!!</h1>
{% else %}
    <form method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.username.label }}
        {{ form.username() }}
        </br>
        {{ form.email.label }}
        {{ form.email() }}
        </br>
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And remember to use that commented out `form.validate_on_submit()` in your `POST` route.